# how to set the sitecore wizard form default height

Tags: xaml, sitecore

When a wizard form show in sitecore backend, how to set the default form height? currently the default popup form is not tall enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string width = "208px”;
string height = "190px”;
Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowModalDialog("/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/your.custom.xaml.aspx", width, height, String.Empty, true);
```

The modal dialog size is being persisted within user profile so when testing, login with different users.

Hope this helps